# confused by tensorflow output

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code, and related output. Confused why there are two different output of shape for the same tensor? One is `shape=(3, 1)`, the other is `shape=(2,)`?

```
import tensorflow.google as tf
tensor = tf.constant([[1.], [1.], [1.]])
print tensor
print tf.shape(tensor)
```

Output,

```
Tensor("Const_0:0", shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Shape_0:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first output for

```
print tensor
```

tells you the information (dimension) of that tensor. That is a tensor of three rows and one column.

However, the

```
tf.shape(tensor)
```

returns a 1-D integer **tensor** representing the shape of input. Therefore the output you see is the information (shape) about the returned tensor which you can see using:

```
tensor.get_shape()

> TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(1)])
```

which indeed, has two values.

Comment: Thanks, and another confusion is for `tensor = tf.constant([[1.], [1.], [1.]])`, it defines one tensor with 3*1 dimension, or 3 tensor with 1*1 dimension?

Comment: As indicated by the output `Tensor("Const_0:0", shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)` you get one tensor with dimension 3x1.

Comment: Thanks, and in my original output, `shape=(2,)` means what kinds of shape, it means 2 * what dimension? Just curious.

Comment: As stated in my post, it is a one dimensional tensor (or a vector). So it's a vector of 2 elements: `[3,1]` | It is NOT a 1x2 tensor! That would be  a two dimensional tensor (or a matrix) and would look like this `[[1,2]]` (notice the two sets of brackets).

Answer (score 1):

Since `tf.shape(tensor)` would return a shape object. And when you `print` it out, it is actually the information about the shape object, i.e. shape=(2,) which is not the shape of the tensor but the shape of `shape` object.

For more details, check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape_n)

Comment: Thanks, but why it is `shape=(2,)`?

Comment: It’s because “shape of tensor” = (3,1), so shape of “shape of tensor” = (2,) which is the shape of (3,1)

Comment: Thanks, but what does `(2,)` mean for shape? It means 2 * what dimensions?

Comment: Because it's a tuple, if you need to declare a single value in a tuple, you need to add comma at the end of it. Read [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) for details.

Comment: Do you mean the return of `tf.shape(tensor)` is a tuple other than another tensor?

Comment: I mean the return  of `tf.shape` is equal to `(tensor)Tensor("Shape_0:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`, in which, the `shape=` is actually a tuple. That's why you got `(2,)` instead of `2`.